# Oracle maf and oracle af

Tags: ios, cordova, oracle-adf, oracle-maf

Some information required about MAF.

How many platforms it will support?

I have read in some blogs, for client side(Mobile) they are using web frameworks and for Business logic they are using java and cordova for interact with Mobile functionalities.

Here business logic(JAVA) mean client side business logic or server side?

Using MAF directly(From mobile) we can access database, without interaction of webservices?

Is there any wrapper between Mobile and oracle database?

in case without wrapper we can, how to put security for database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAF supports iOS and Android currently - versions [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/maf/documentation/maf222certmatrix-2879089.html). See the [data sheet](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/maf/documentation/oraclemaf-datasheet-2220993.pdf) for more info.

MAF can execute Java code (compiled at deployment) natively on the device. Java can be used for local business logic, although typically business logic is performed on server and accessed via Web Service for obvious performance and design  reasons.

Java is typically used on device to support application state and behaviors or interface. UI is coded using component-based framework called AMX which generates HTML for rendering in web view and task flows for graphical design of navigation, or hand coded using HTML/JS fwk of your choice. Cordova provides access to on-device features via drag and drop code generation for AMX pages, as well as Java and JS APIs.

Java is used to connect to Web Services (REST and SOAP - REST preferred for performance) and the local database, (encrypted) SQLite via JDBC. All interaction with remote data sources is via Java JDBC and or Web Services. Java is used to wrapper all data sources, local and remote.

Please feel free to look at all the docs on the [Oracle OTN site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/maf/overview/index.html). Lots of good info there. Also, my [aggregation site](https://sites.google.com/site/joeztechland/adf-mobile) for my Oracle students has lots of good links as well.