# What is Oracle MAF

Tags: oracle-maf

I am new to the World of Oracle MAF.Could anyone help me to describe what is Oracle MAF and the key concepts of Oracle MAf?  It will be helpful for me to understand

Comment: Why not the [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/maf/overview/index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle Mobile Application Framework (Oracle MAF) is a hybrid-mobile framework that enables developers to rapidly develop single-source applications and deploy to both the Apple iOS and Google Android platforms. Oracle MAF provides a complete MVC development framework - that leverage Java, HTML5 and JavaScript - with declarative user interface definition, device services integration and built-in security. Oracle MAF maximizes code reuse and results in faster development of compelling mobile applications.

### Concepts of MAF

1. Visual and declarative development
2. Mobile optimized user experience
3. Simplified access to device services
4. Code in Java and run on multiple mobile OSs
5. Offline support using encrypted SQLite
6. Built-in security for authentication, authorization and encryption support

### Features and Benefits

1.Develop once, deploy to multiple mobile devices and platforms including iOS, Android and Windows. 
2. Choose your preferred development language Java or JavaScript

3. Leverage Over 80 components for simpler development of richer user interfaces
4. Accelerate development through visual & declarative application development
5. Choose your preferred IDE - Oracle JDeveloper or Eclipse
6. Access native device services, such as phone, SMS, camera, GPS and more
7. Integrate both on-device and browser-based mobile interfaces into the same applications
8. Leverage existing skills to develop mobile applications using open standard technologies (Java, HTML5, JavaScript, CSS)
9. Supports both real-time and offline data access
10. Offline support using SQLite – encryption included
11. Build secure mobile applications with end-to-end encryption on a proven platform

Comment: Thanks for the quick description

Comment: Its Ok. There are several documentations are there for MAF. Pleas go through them

Answer (score 0):

A good pace to start with MAF are the free online videos that Oracle has posted, [here](https://www.youtube.com/user/OracleMobilePlatform). Main oracle MAF site on OTN, [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/maf/overview/index.html). Tutorials [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/maf/learnmore/index.html#tutorials). More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739668/oracle-maf-and-oracle-af).